# Cakephp - Change directory (absolute windows path) with Folder::cd() doesn't work

Tags: windows, api, cakephp, path, directory

i can't set the absolute windows path with the help of the methods Folder::cd() or Folder Constructor from cakephp api. 
There are no errors or messages after method call.

Example

```
//path= C:".DS."Users".DS."User.Name".DS."Desktop".DS."Qualitätssicherung".DS."Testmanagement"
$fol = new Folder($path); 
print_r($fol->errors()); // empty
echo $fol->path; // empty
```

Other path definitions i tried:

```
C:\Users\User.Name\Desktop\Qualitätssicherung\Testmanagement
C:\\Users\\User.Name\\Desktop\\Qualitätssicherung\\Testmanagement
```

Should i use something like escaping or a special function to generate a valid path string?

PS: I'm using the latest version of cakephp :)

### Solution

Found here: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502685/php-file-handling-with-utf-8-special-characters)

Problem was the special char **ä** in the path var. This code handle it:

```
$string = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($string, "auto"), 'Windows-1252', $string);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem was the special char ä I found a solution here which works for me:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502685/php-file-handling-with-utf-8-special-characters)

```
$string = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($string, "auto"), 'Windows-1252', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you need two back slashes after drive name in windows so: `'C:\\Users\User.Name\Desktop\Qualitätssicherung\Testmanagement'`