# UTF-8, PHP, Win7 - Is there a solution now to save UTF-8-filenames on Win 7 using php?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, windows-7, filenames

> Update: Just to not make you reading through all: PHP starting with
>   7.1.0alpha2 supports UTF-8 filenames on Windows. (Thanks to Anatol-Belski!)

Following some link chains on stackoverflow I found part of the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10138133/3716796  by Umberto Salsi

(and on the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950046/3716796  by Artefacto)

In short: 'PHP communicate[s] with the underlying file system as a **"non-Unicode aware program"**', and because of that all filenames given to PHP by Windows and vice versa are automatically translated/reencoded by Windows. This causes the errors. And you seemingly can't stop the automatic reencoding.
(And https://stackoverflow.com/a/2888039/3716796  by Artefacto: 
"**PHP does not use the wide WIN32 API** calls, so you're limited by the codepage.")
And at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47096  there is the bug report for PHP.

> **Though on there nicolas suggests, that a COM-object might work!** 
> **$fs = new COM('Scripting.FileSystemObject', null,
>   CP_UTF8);**

Maybe I will try that sometimes.
***So there is the part of my questionleft : Is there PHP6 out, or was it withdrawn, or is there anything new on PHP about that topic?***

// full Question
The most questions about this topic are 1 to 5 years old.
Could php now save a file using
file_put_contents($dir . '/' . $_POST['fileName'], $_POST['content']);

when the $_POST['fileName'] is UTF-8 encoded, for example "Крым.xml" ?
Currently it is saved as
ÐšÑ€Ñ‹Ð¼.xml

I checked the fileName variable, so I can be sure it's UTF-8:
echo mb_detect_encoding($_POST['fileName']);

1. Is there now anything new in PHP that could accomplish it?
2. At some places I read PHP 6 would be able to do it, but PHP 6 if i I remember right, has been withdrawn. ?
3. In Windows Explorer I can change the name of a file to "Крым.xml". As far as I have understood the old questions&answers, it should be possible to use file_put_contents if the fileName-var is simply encoded to the encoding used by windows 7 and it's NTFS disc.
   There is even 3 old question with answers that claim to have succeeded:
    [PHP File Handling with UTF-8 Special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502685/php-file-handling-with-utf-8-special-characters)

    [Convert UTF-16LE to UTF-8 in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980068/how-to-convert-utf-16le-to-utf-8-in-php)

    and [PHP: How to create unicode filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467501/php-how-to-create-unicode-filenames)

   Overall and most approved answers say it is not possible. 
   I checked all suggested answers already myself, and none works.
4. How to definitly and with absolute accuracy find out, in which encoding my Win 7 and Explorer saves the filename on my NTFS disc and with German language setting?
   As said: I can create a file "Крым.xml" in the Explorer.

My conclusion: 
1. Either file_put_contents doesn'T work correctly when handing over the fileName (which I tried with conversions to UTF-16, UTF-16LE, ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252) to Windows, 

2. or file_put_contents just doesn't implement a way to call Windows' own file function in the appropriate way (so this second possibility would mean it's not a bug but just not implemented.) (For example notepad++ has no problems creating, writing and renaming a file called Крым.xml.)

Just one example of the error messages I got, in this case when I used 
mb_convert_encoding($theFilename , 'Windows-1252' , 'UTF-8')

"Warning: file_put_contents(dirToSaveIn/????.xml): failed to open stream: No error in C:\aa xampp\htdocs\myinterface.lo\myinterface\phpWriteLocalSearchResponseXML.php on line 26 "
With other conversion I got other error messages, ranging from 'invalid characters' to no string recognized at all.

Greetings
John

Comment: Until the day that Windows filesystem can magically work with every charset known to mankind, then DON'T DO THIS

Comment: And this is nothing to do with PHP, and everything to do with operating system filesystems: try it in Perl, Python, Ruby, Java, Go, Haskell, etc

Comment: @MarkBaker : It's (obviously) not Windows' causing this, but PHP.exe running as a "non-Unicode aware program".
Other .exe-programs can communicate with Windows accordingly.
(That's why already in my original question I pointed out that Notepad++ can create, write and rename such files.)

Comment: It's something you can't guarantee on any platform, so PHP (which is multiplatform) doesn't look at what charsets the filesystem supports, and nor do many other programming languages.... typically only native apps are in a position to do that.... which is why it's not a good idea to use non-ASCII characters in any filename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP starting with 7.1.0alpha2 supports UTF-8 filenames on Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: Just in case anyone would need it, here is a PHP script which scans dirs and mass-converts file names into some other encoding: https://github.com/chang-zhao/encoding/ I used it to convert thousands of TXT files from "gibberish utf8" of old PHP into new readable ones.